# DevExpress - How do I dynamically modify button caption within a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, devexpress, datagridviewcolumn

Please help me with a problem with Devexpress.

[How do I dynamically modify button caption within a datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHntx.jpg)?

For example: In the column "Total Sale" if the value is below 100 the button must have the caption "Low Value", now if the value above 101 the button must show "Above Value"

As I say this, please help me, thank you

```
        private void bandedGridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Caption == "bandedGridColumn1")
        {
            int val = Convert.ToInt32(bandedGridView1.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "VAGAS"));
            RepositoryItemButtonEdit ritem = new RepositoryItemButtonEdit();
            if (val == 20)
            {
                ritem.TextEditStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.TextEditStyles.HideTextEditor;
                ritem.Buttons[0].Caption = "Gerar Sorteio";
                ritem.Buttons[0].Visible = false;
                e.RepositoryItem = ritem;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your solution looks correct to me. The CustomRowCellEdit event is the correct place to dynamically assign an in-place editor to a single row cell. What is the issue you are facing? And why are you setting the RepositoryItemButtonEdit's button visibility to false?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

I just want to change the caption of the button according to the value of each line obtained, I can't do that.

on the issue of hiding, that was just a test that I was doing.

Do you know how to change the button name according to the value of each line?

Comment: Here it´s the print the windows form  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHntx.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer My Question

- I Criated a method called ApresentaBotoesNoDataGrid()

private void ApresentaBotoesNoDataGrid()
{

```
        RepositoryItemButtonEdit riBtnEditMatricular = new RepositoryItemButtonEdit();
        riBtnEditMatricular.Name = "riBtnEditMatricular";
        riBtnEditMatricular.Buttons[0].Kind = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Glyph;
        riBtnEditMatricular.Buttons[0].Caption = "Matricular";
        riBtnEditMatricular.ButtonsStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BorderStyles.Office2003;
        riBtnEditMatricular.Buttons[0].Appearance.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
        riBtnEditMatricular.TextEditStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.TextEditStyles.HideTextEditor;
        riBtnEditMatricular.ButtonClick += AcaoBotaoDataGrid_ButtonClick;

        RepositoryItemButtonEdit riBtnEditSortear = new RepositoryItemButtonEdit();
        riBtnEditSortear.Name = "riBtnEditSortear";
        riBtnEditSortear.Buttons[0].Kind = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Glyph;
        riBtnEditSortear.Buttons[0].Caption = "Sortear";
        riBtnEditSortear.ButtonsStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BorderStyles.Office2003;
        riBtnEditSortear.Buttons[0].Appearance.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 240, 208);
        riBtnEditSortear.TextEditStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.TextEditStyles.HideTextEditor;
        riBtnEditSortear.ButtonClick += AcaoBotaoDataGrid_ButtonClick;
    
        dtgQuadroSorteio.RepositoryItems.Add(riBtnEditMatricular);
        dtgQuadroSorteio.RepositoryItems.Add(riBtnEditSortear);
        bandedGridView1.CustomRowCellEdit += bandedGridView1_CustomRowCellEdit;
        bandedGridView1.RowCellStyle += bandedGridView1_RowCellStyle;

    }
```

- Other method called AcaoBotaoDataGrid_ButtonClick

void AcaoBotaoDataGrid_ButtonClick(object sender, ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
{
var value = bandedGridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("CODELETIVA");

```
        ButtonEdit buttonEdit = (ButtonEdit)sender;
        if (buttonEdit.Properties.Name == "riBtnEditMatricular" && e.Button.Kind == DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Glyph)
        {
            XtraMessageBox.Show("Receive Button Clicked on row handle " + value.ToString());
        }
        else if (buttonEdit.Properties.Name == "riBtnEditSortear" && e.Button.Kind == DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Glyph)
        {
            XtraMessageBox.Show("Pay Now Button Clicked on row handle " + value.ToString());
        }

    }
```

- Event

  ```
    private void bandedGridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.FieldName != "Button") return;
        BandedGridView view = (BandedGridView)sender;
        string type = (string)view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "TEMPERATURA");
        if (type == "Grande Procura")
            e.RepositoryItem = dtgQuadroSorteio.RepositoryItems["riBtnEditSortear"]; 
        else
            e.RepositoryItem = dtgQuadroSorteio.RepositoryItems["riBtnEditMatricular"];
    }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For the caption to be made visible, you need to set the RepositoryItemButtonEdit's [Kind](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton.Kind) property to Glyph.

Comment: Friend Brendon, thanks again, but I don't know how to do that, I'm new to developing windows form C # with devexpress.
could you write what the code would look like, please.

Comment: ritem.Buttons[0].Kind = ButtonKinds.Glyph

Comment: Hi Brendon!  It didn't work, ButtonKinds shows "does not exist in the current context"

And the worst thing is that the event doesn't even work anymore.

I am desperate, please friend, you will be able to see how I can do this, please.

Comment: I don't have DevExpress WinForms currently installed, but if you were to just type "riitem.Buttons[0].Kind = ", Visual Studio intellisense should offer the correct enum type for auto-complete.

Comment: Try ButtonPredefines.Glyph

Comment: Brendon, please look at my publication on this link, I believe this new post is easier to explain and also the problem I need to solve, I don’t know how to do it, I’m not good at developing, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67372444/devexpress-how-do-i-change-the-button-inside-datagridview-automatically/67381004?noredirect=1#comment119103841_67381004

Comment: I've seen that ticket and I can tell you that using the CustomRowCellEdit event is the way to go. You're on the right track here.