# Devexpress - How do I change the button Inside DataGridView automatically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol

I need to modify the description of the button name that is inside the datagridview

I'm using DevExpress - WindowsForm - C #

How do I change the button line by line automatically based on the value of my cell "TYPE"?

For example: In the "TYPE" column, when the cell value is "Service" the button displays the description "Receive" and when the cell value is "Expense" the button description appears as "Pay now".

[image]

Comment: The best way to do this is with a *data binding.*  Have a look [here](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2389/common-features/data-binding/how-to-bind-a-control-to-data-created-at-runtime) for some examples.

Comment: How is this different than your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67327943/devexpress-how-do-i-dynamically-modify-button-caption-within-a-datagridview

Comment: Hello Friends, thanks for the explanation.

Brendon, I opened a new question because the other was a little difficult to understand, but I followed your explanation and nothing happened.

Robert, I had seen this ticket on devexpress but I didn't understand anything.

there was a friend here who posted a loop but it is wrong, I want to change the button name and cell number.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgr in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {

                if (!dgr.IsNewRow)
                {
                    if (dgr.Cells[3].Value=="SERVICE")
                    {
                        dgr.Cells[4].Value = "Receive"; 
                    }
                    else if (dgr.Cells[3].Value == "Expense")
                    {
                        dgr.Cells[4].Value = "Pay now"; 
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hello nightman, thank you very much for the explanation, in fact it is a button that I need to change the description that is inside the datagridview and not the cell.

I'm using the DevExpress datagridview, do you know how to do it?

Comment: hi, I do not fully understand. Can you give a more explanatory example?

Comment: Yes of course

I have a datagridview from DevExpress, inside that datagridview there is a column with buttons, as the values ​​of the Type column are modified, the button of the corresponding line must be changed only the caption of the button, as I highlighted the buttons in green and yellow.

understand my friend?

Comment: I tried to do it but the "for" is assigning the button description to all the cells and the correct one should only be for those cells that have the "TYPE" different from each other, what am I doing wrong?